# How to do a 1:1 clone of APFS disk?

Tags: macos, hard-drive, apfs, bootable-disk

I want to clone my internal drive to an external one, byte for byte, partition table to partition table. My MBP is using GPT with APFS, the standard now-a-days. I do not have a T2 chip, but I do have a T1 chip. My internal drive is 500GB as is the external drive. Though, I think the issue may lie in the fact that my internal drive has a sector size of 4086 bytes and my external drive has a sector size of 512 bytes.

I tried to use `dd` in recovery mode using the command `dd if=/dev/disk0 of=/dev/disk4 bs=100m` but it was going super slow at 18 - 19 MB/s. (USB 3.1 SSD).

I booted into Linux and did a copy of the drive (using `dd if=/dev/nvme01 of=/dev/sdb`) and it was much faster at 270 MB/s. I also was able to test within a virtual machine and got the same 270 MB/s speed. I confirmed that the first 100 MB between the drives were the same (used `dd` and `md5sum`).

I also confirmed the same way in recovery using `dd` and `md5`. But the drive didn’t have a partition table and macOS just read the drive as having something like 65 GB and refused to mount it.

So I recreated the partition map using *parted* and then restored the partitions. But macOS still refused to do anything with it. I’m guessing I need to `dd` the synthesized disk from macOS but there is obviously something wrong with the USB driver since it’s writing so slowly.

I also tried copying the partition tables using `sfdisk` but it failed because “*first lba specified by script is out of range*”.

I've also tried using `cat` (`cat /dev/disk0 > /dev/disk4`) and that didn't change the speed at all, so it's not `dd`.

Here is the output of `diskutil list`:

```
-bash-3.2# diskutil list
/dev/disk0 (internal):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                         500.3 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     314.6 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk2         500.0 GB   disk0s2

/dev/disk1 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        +2.1 GB     disk1
   1:                  Apple_HFS macOS Base System       2.0 GB     disk1s1

/dev/disk2 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +500.0 GB   disk2
                                 Physical Store disk0s2
   1:                APFS Volume Macintosh HD            288.0 GB   disk2s1
   2:                APFS Volume Preboot                 64.6 MB    disk2s2
   3:                APFS Volume Recovery                1.0 GB     disk2s3
   4:                APFS Volume VM                      1.1 GB     disk2s4

/dev/disk3 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +5.2 MB     disk3

/dev/disk4 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *500.3 GB   disk4
   1:                        EFI EFI                     314.6 MB   disk4s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk5         500.0 GB   disk4s2

/dev/disk5 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +ERROR      disk5
                                 Physical Store disk4s2

/dev/disk6 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +524.3 KB   disk6

/dev/disk7 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +524.3 KB   disk7

/dev/disk8 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +524.3 KB   disk8

/dev/disk9 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +2.1 MB     disk9

/dev/disk10 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +524.3 KB   disk10

/dev/disk11 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +524.3 KB   disk11

/dev/disk12 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +12.6 MB    disk12

/dev/disk13 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +4.2 MB     disk13

/dev/disk14 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +1.0 MB     disk14

/dev/disk15 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +2.1 MB     disk15

/dev/disk16 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +524.3 KB   disk16

/dev/disk17 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +524.3 KB   disk17

/dev/disk18 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +1.0 MB     disk18

/dev/disk19 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +524.3 KB   disk19

/dev/disk20 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +6.3 MB     disk20

/dev/disk21 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +6.3 MB     disk21

/dev/disk22 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +524.3 KB   disk22

/dev/disk23 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +2.1 MB     disk23
```

Comment: The disk is GPT not APFS.  APFS is a filessystem stored in one (or more) partitions.  You can definitely use  `dd` command to copy the whole disk (including partition tables, EFI partition etc).  You would want to copy the physical disk not synthesized.  If it was slow please edit question with exact `dd` command including `bs` parameter.  If you just want to copy APFS to an existing partition on backup disk you could use free version of [superduper](https://shirt-pocket.com/SuperDuper/SuperDuperDescription.html) or use `dd` to copy just the partition and make sure destination had type `AF0A`

Comment: [continued] note *superduper* doesn't do a 1:1 copy like `dd` - it leaves out some temp files etc as recommended by Apple but it depends what you are trying to achieve - it will make a bootable copy of APFS container.

Comment: @lx07 Hi, thanks for taking the time. I've updated my post.

Comment: Thanks for the edit.  Please update your question with `diskutil list` but if you did `dd if=/dev/disk1` then most likely you are copying from the **synthesized** disk.  This will not copy the partition table and will put unreadable information on the destination.  You want to copy from the **physical** disk (disk0).  Try `dd if=/dev/disk0 of=/dev/disk4 bs=100m` (assuming *disk4` is your second physical drive).

Comment: @lx07 Thanks for the edits, no worries, I was on mobile so formatting was shoddy. I added the output of diskutil list. I realized I said disk1 but I meant disk0, promise. (I updated that in my post).

Comment: @Kyle What's the purpose of the clone?

Comment: @klanomath Transferring the data from one machine to the other. I don't trust migration assistant and copying files manually usually messes up hard links, permissions, etc. However, I figured it out. I'm going to be posting my answer soon.

Comment: In my opinion the best method is: 1) shrink (apfs container) disk0s2 slightly 2) reformat disk4 to 1 hfs+ partition 3) `asr -source disk2 -target disk4s2 -erase`

Comment: @Kyle, just FYI, [Restic](https://restic.net/) is a great incremental/snapshot-based backup tool with POSIX filesystem support as one of its main features. It currently supports POSIX file permissions, and does support symlinks, but doesn't support hard links.

Answer (score 5):

The `asr` command is the native tool to clone data and handles all Apple metadata, file systems and APFS / core storage structures. If no one can help, worst case is to restore from a backup and use `asr` rather than `dd` the data destroyer.

I partially joke about `dd` - it’s more useful than just destroying disks, but [on several macOS filesystems, you don’t want a perfect clone of the drive](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/380497/5472) identifiers in almost all cases - you want the data moved and not the entire structure and instantiation of what was designed as a unique filesystem identifier and the associated data that you do want to move.

Comment: @lx07 *dd* actually bit-for-bit copies everything. But sometimes/often this isn't a good idea because all UUIDs (partition/volumes/apfs (container/physical etc.)) are identical/exist twice afterwards. So it depends on the scenario/intention...

Comment: @klanomath I’ve linked to your superior answer on using asr with core storage to illustrate volume copies and not disk copies as the correct path for general cloning.

Comment: I've tested both asr cases (cs > external disk partition & apfs > external disk partition) in VMs. They ended differently: a cs source LV converts to an hfs+ partition on the target disk; an apfs container scheme source (**no localsnapshots allowed - if I understand the man pages correctly)!** is just "replicated/copied" to a new container scheme (with system/data/recovery/preboot - vm is created automatically after booting from the target disk) on the target disk.

Answer (score 1):

You can absolutely use `dd` to clone your MacOS disk that has an APFS partition. The issue is that your source and target do not share the same sector size. This isn't a huge issue, though, as the only thing that matters is that the partitions are aligned to the sectors, not the data within them. So if you erase the target disk in Disk Utility selecting GUID and APFS as the scheme and format, then the partitions will be aligned. Then use dd to clone the individual partitions. That's it!

Also, regarding the slow copy, you need to use /dev/rdisk0 and not /dev/disk0.

Comment: Not really true: the gpt of 512B disks are slightly smaller than the gpt of 4k disks! So a disk0(512) to disk4(4k) with the same size will fail (or better: the gpt is somehow irregular). GPT(512) is 1 pmbr + 1 gpt header + 32 table: first new block (alligned to 4k)=40. GPT(4k) is 1 pmbr + 1 gpt header + 4 table: first new block=6 (=48 (512blocks)). Keep in mind: block numbering starts with block0!

Comment: @klanomath Got a source for this? To my knowledge, physical sector size is irrelevant, since GPT assumes a logical block size of 512 bytes, regardless; the partition tables are always typically 34 blocks, i.e. 17KiB.

Comment: @JivanPal I simply compared the GPT of a 512 and a 4096 disk (at home) with hexdump/hexfiend. The reason is the "waste of space" for the PMBR and the GPT header. Each requires 512 Byte but occupies a whole 4096 block.

Comment: @klanomath Are you sure about that? That seems highly unusual to me, especially since every drive I've dealt with, including my current SSD (Kingston A400) does not operate this way. PMBR starts a byte 0 (LBA 0), GPT header @ byte 512 (LBA 1), GPT entries from LBA 2 to end of LBA 33 (byte 1024 to 17407). When formatted, `gdisk`, for example, uses a sector alignment value of 8 logical blocks, so partition 1 starts at LBA 40 by default. Even in Disk Utility, this behaviour appears to be the same.

Comment: @JivanPal 3 different common block sizes exist: 512, 512e (512 emulated but in fact 4096) and 4096. 512 and 512e are "formatted" with the 1-33 gpt (+0=pmbr) and 4096 with the 1-5 gpt (+0=pmbr) in macOS. Real 512 devices are really rare now.

Comment: @klanomath, I actually can't find any reference to the physical block size of my SSD (it's not mentioned in any spec sheets), but I have no reason to doubt that it's 4096 bytes but reports 512-byte logical sectors (i.e. effectively 512e). As for 4K Native, I honestly can't say I've come across any such drives in the wild. You've helped correct my understanding of 512e and 4Kn, though, so thanks

Comment: @JivanPal I have some at home (e.g. an external 10TB Western Digital). Sometimes the USB2SATA controller intervenes and reports a 512e device as 4Kn only device to the system - which is a problem if you format the disk internally and use this disk in such an enclosure later. Other example: [Recover Corrupt SSHD](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/256487/recover-corrupt-sshd)

Comment: @klanomath Good to know — for that kind of cross-compatibility reason, among others, I assumed that the GPT spec defined a block as 512 bytes in all cases. It kind of seems like an oversight that they didn't define it that way, especially given that UEFI has to read 128-byte partition entries anyway.

Answer (score -2):

Best solution I found is to use Paragon Hard Disk Manager 17 Advanced in Windows. Simply clone to new drive. It does require a Windows boot partition or putting the source and destination drives in external cases but not really deal.

Comment: It can't even read APFS…  & what possible use is a Windows boot partition on a Mac. You didn't even read the question.